# how to create automatic system date in sql without store whenever click the button

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

Hi I have one button named **"Pay"**. User click so many times this button. Everytime it will create the current date in the column **date** in the table **purchase**.

How to do this in sql server 2008? Any hope?

Comment: "I have one button ..." not in SQL Server you don't. SQL Server doesn't have any facilities for building user interfaces. So, there's some other technology involved that you haven't told us about. And you've not demonstrated any effort yourself.

Comment: I have button in Visual studio. when i click this button system date stored into db.

Comment: Visual Studio supports several languages (VB.Net, C#, F#, etc), and several UI technologies (WPF, WinForms, Store, ASP.NET).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while inserting into table insert this value for the column where you want to save current date details `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 2):

To insert a record with corrent timestamp you can write a sql width `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (date) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

If you have other columns ont the `Orders` table, your SQL will go like as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (date,....) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,.....)
```

This function `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the ANSI SQL equivalent to GETDATE(), and you can also write this as fllows:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (date) VALUES(GETDATE())
```

The document is here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751(v=sql.90).aspx